# Deploy springboot executable with Maven to Nexus

Tags: spring-boot, maven, deployment, nexus

I'm using Maven to build my executable Spring-Boot and I also use the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.psmonster.wfe</groupId>
  <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.1.1</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven2</id>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
      </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxp-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
      <artifactId>Saxon-B</artifactId>
      <version>9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>saxon-releases</name>
      <url>${env.MAVEN_REPO_URL}/repository/WFESRV/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

 <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.8.1</version>
           <executions>
              <execution>
                 <id>default-deploy</id>
                 <phase>deploy</phase>
                 <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                 </goals>
              </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
         <execution>
          <goals>
           <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
         </execution>
        </executions>
       </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0.1746</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                <mainClass>base.Application</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run this:

```
mvn  $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean package spring-boot:repackage -Dmaven.test.skip=true -q
```

The myPSMonster.jar is build well, and I can run that in my Docker Container.
So to I just want to push it to my Nexus Artifactory I just add **deploy** after repackage.
Then the nice jar will be overwritten and a tiny jar with only the compiled code will be pushed.

Does somebody know how to fix this without using deploy:deploy-file?

Comment: do not bind the spring-boot-maven plugin to deploy phase.. Keep as documented in phase the plugin does itself (cause it knows how to handle it)..`mvn clean deploy`...

Comment: Sorry I pasted the wrong content in here. I edit the above.

Comment: Does not change my previous comment. Use simply `mvn clean deploy` no goal calling...why are you manually calling the `spring-boot:repackage` goal?

Comment: because if I do that `mvn clean deploy` it pushes only 7.4k to the Nexus.

Comment: I edit and added the whole POM. Maybe you can see better what I did wrong. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the maven deploy plugin to deploy the archive .There are other plugins available to perform this task . And if you are using jenkins, the deploy setup could be managed differently through jenkins plugin as well. But for now, using maven in your local machine we could setup the `.m2 settings file` with the nexus server credentials. After that you could configure your `pom.xml` with the following :

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>${repository_url}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

The above part will tell maven where to push the artifact during the deployment process.Once this is setup, you could use the plugin :

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.1</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>default-deploy</id>
         <phase>deploy</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>deploy</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin
```

The Maven-deploy plugin is linked to the `deployment` phase of the maven lifecycle .Then you could use the following command to push the jar/war to the repository :

```
mvn clean deploy -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: @markus0074 Could you be more clear. So , your jar is getting pushed into nexus but the size of the jar is small (not fatJar) ? Is that your issue ?

Comment: Yes. The jar doesn't include the springboot stuff.

Answer (score 1):

So. finally it fixed it by using this:

```
- mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=pom.xml -DrepositoryId=central
                              -Dfile=target/saxon-0.1.$CI_PIPELINE_ID.jar
                              -Durl=http://psmonster:8081/repository/WFESRV/
```